# Can I use local resources for mp4 playback?

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, video-streaming, flet

I am trying to use **flet** to play a local MP4 file.

When [I read the reference](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/video/), I found that their shown code example is using only "http" resources:

```
sample_media =  [
                    ft.VideoMedia("https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28951144/229373720-14d69157-1a56-4a78-a2f4-d7a134d7c3e9.mp4"),
                    ft.VideoMedia("https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28951144/229373718-86ce5e1d-d195-45d5-baa6-ef94041d0b90.mp4")
                ]
```

**Question:**
Can I use a local resource (file) for MP4 playback using **flet**, and how?
There was no example of specifying a local video. Does that mean it can't be done with **flet**?

**Whay I've tried:**
I changed the URL from `http` to `./video/movie.mp4`, but it did not work.

Environment : Mac
Language : Python
Library : flet

```
import random
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.theme_mode = ft.ThemeMode.LIGHT
    page.title = "TheEthicalVideo"
    page.window_always_on_top = True
    page.spacing = 20
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

    def handle_pause(e):
        video.pause()
        print("Video.pause()")

    def handle_play_or_pause(e):
        video.play_or_pause()
        print("Video.play_or_pause()")

    def handle_play(e):
        video.play()
        print("Video.play()")

    sample_media = [
        ft.VideoMedia(
            "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28951144/229373709-603a7a89-2105-4e1b-a5a5-a6c3567c9a59.mp4",
            extras={
                "artist": "Thousand Foot Krutch",
                "album": "The End Is Where We Begin",
            },
            http_headers={
                "Foo": "Bar",
                "Accept": "*/*",
            },
        ),
    ]

    page.add(
        video := ft.Video(
            expand=True,
            playlist=sample_media[0:2],
            playlist_mode=ft.PlaylistMode.LOOP,
            fill_color=ft.colors.BLUE_400,
            aspect_ratio=16/9,
            volume=100,
            autoplay=False,
            filter_quality=ft.FilterQuality.HIGH,
            muted=False,
            on_loaded=lambda e: print("Video loaded successfully!"),
            on_enter_fullscreen=lambda e: print("Video entered fullscreen!"),
            on_exit_fullscreen=lambda e: print("Video exited fullscreen!"),
        ),
        ft.Row(
            wrap=True,
            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
            controls=[
                ft.ElevatedButton("Play", on_click=handle_play),
                ft.ElevatedButton("Pause", on_click=handle_pause),
                ft.ElevatedButton("Play Or Pause", on_click=handle_play_or_pause),
                ft.ElevatedButton("Stop", on_click=handle_stop),
                ft.ElevatedButton("Next", on_click=handle_next),
                ft.ElevatedButton("Previous", on_click=handle_previous),
                ft.ElevatedButton("Seek s=10", on_click=handle_seek),
                ft.ElevatedButton("Jump to first Media", on_click=handle_jump),
                ft.ElevatedButton("Add Random Media", on_click=handle_add_media),
                ft.ElevatedButton("Remove Random Media", on_click=handle_remove_media),
            ],
        ),
        ft.Slider(
            min=0,
            value=100,
            max=100,
            label="Volume = {value}%",
            divisions=10,
            width=400,
            on_change=handle_volume_change,
        ),
        ft.Slider(
            min=1,
            value=1,
            max=3,
            label="PlaybackRate = {value}X",
            divisions=6,
            width=400,
            on_change=handle_playback_rate_change,
        ),
    )


ft.app(target=main)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.